# Java: Help with basic outputting basic value arithmetic. Getting 0 for output, don't know why?

Tags: java, math, big-o

I am having some issues doing basic math with Java. I don't know why I am getting 0 as a result of multiplying n*n*n only in one case. (see below) I need this not to be zero because I have to divide timing/n*n*n to get that big O performance. Also if I can get that working the output may look like 0.00000 but I want to multiply that by like 100,000 just so I can see numbers and find any trends in performance.

You can see the values of n and timing in the first two number columns.

- n is **Integer**
- timing is **Long**

This is my output statement,

```
System.out.println(fmt.format("%20s %20d %20d %20d %20d %20d%n", "Alg. 1", n, timing, n*n*n, timing/(n*n), timing /*((double)timing/((double)n*Math.log((double)n)))*/));
```

My results,

```
 Alg. 1                  256                    4             16777216                    0                    4
 Alg. 1                  512                   22            134217728                    0                   22
 Alg. 1                 1024                  173           1073741824                    0                  173
 Alg. 1                 2048                 1362                    0                    0                 1362
```

Please keep in mind I need to perform this log math also. Any tips or fixes for that would also be appreciated!

**Note**: I am not dividing at all in the statement n*n*n and I am getting 0 in column four row four.

Can someone also please tell me how to get this to output decimal places that are accurate not just 0.000000. My new arithmetic is ((float)(timing/((long)n)*n*n)*100000. I am multiplying by 100000 as said above because I want to see something in the decimal places. I should be seeing 0.0159139 with this equation when n is 2048 and timing is 1362. I just see 0.000000 though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2048<sup>3</sup> is 2<sup>33</sup> which overflows using 32-bit arithmetic. Use a `long` or a `double` to handle numbers this big.

```
((long) n) * n * n
```

[(Demo at ideone.com)](http://ideone.com/dHZ0k)

Comment: Curious why did you cast long on only one n and not the entire statement? Because it would be 0 already by the time long is cast? Worked by the way. Now to divide by that number does there need to be any casting? timing is already a long so if I wanted I could just do timing/((long)n)*n*n?

Comment: Your answer was very helpful and will be accepted, I was just hoping you could help me with one last thing associated with this. I edited the question and asked at the end. @John Kugelman

Answer (score 2):

If you divide one integer by another that's greater than it, you'll get a zero result.

Make either numerator or denominator a double and you'll be fine.

```
System.out.println(fmt.format("%20s %20d %20d %20d %20d %20d%n", "Alg. 1", n, timing, n*n*n, (double)timing/(n*n), timing));
```

Comment: I am not dividing in the statement n*n*n. That is resulting in zero in the last row of the 3rd column.

Comment: Are you saying that "timing/(n*n)" is not dividing?  Did you try the change that I'm suggesting?

Comment: I am saying that if you read through my ENTIRE question you will realize that my question doesn't lye within timing/(n*n) it is n*n*n. I am NOT saying that timing/(n*n) is not dividing, it CLEARLY IS. Thanks for the tip that you answered with but PLEASE next time address the question directly.

Comment: I was trying to answer the question directly.  I just got it wrong.  Next time try not to whine so much.

Answer (score 2):

2048 cubed is 8589934592, much bigger than the max value of an int. It's actually 2 * (2^32). If you try to convert it to a signed 32-bit int, it wraps around twice and you end up with zero. Use longs!